# how i can get MD5 hash in jdk.7.o?

Tags: android, google-maps

when i try to get MD5 hash by using

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\learnwhat.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

only get SHA1 hash i need MD5 hash to  in goole Map api key sing up. how i can get MD5 hash in jdk1.7.0_09?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-v` with command  if you are using jre7 for getting MD5 hash  for Google Map. this command return you both MD5 and SHA1 :

```
 C:\<YOUR_JDK_PATH\bin>keytool -v androiddebugkey -keystore "C:Users\YOUR_NAME\.android
\debug.keystore" -alias alias_name -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: What do u mean? but i got both MD5 and SHA1 on my console

Comment: if you have any issue then you can see this image for reference http://i.stack.imgur.com/7jKLb.png

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : You forgot to put -alias before androiddebugkey. Is it not the command this?: keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias alias -storepass storepass -keypass storepass, and this is not giving MD5.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: I am not getting errors: just not getting MD5. It is not working: on my console, where the version is --> java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you share with us the link to jre7/jdk7 so that we can have the MD5 at least (place and share from your google drive)? It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

using the following command:

`keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore`

-v will force keytool generate md5, sha1, sha256

Comment: It is not working: on my console, where the version is --> java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)