# MD5: Difference in output of keytool.exe in Java 7 and above

Tags: android, windows, md5, code-signing-certificate, java-10

I have raised my concerns in the following thread:

[how i can get MD5 hash in jdk.7.o?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13598324/787399)

and seen threads like:

[Cannot use Java 7 installation if Java 8 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23877735/787399)

and I have also studied:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E74665_01/MOSHP/settings.htm#CIHEFHEF

but no use.

Since I am using JRE/JDK version > 10, I am unable to obtain MD5 from any keystore of my choice using keytools. It is said that MD5 can be obtained from the keystore, if my JRE version is 7.

Also, I have tried and known that when this command is issued inside Android Studio or Eclipse for the Android's default keystore, that is developers keystore, it readily gives MD5 there. So I also had raised the question about how Android Studio or Eclipse is able to do that when my JRE version is > 10?

So I am trying to find the solution, other way round, for the same problem.

1. In what way, I can still be able to use features of JRE/JDK v7, while v10 remained installed? In what way, I can be able to specify in java control panel in Window 7 (that is my OS), that I want to use Java 7.
2. It is difficult for me to get `"Support Identifier"` information, for the oracle support, to get that version. So someone can guide me how to obtain that as well.

Please search for `"Java SE 7, and Java SE 6 updates"` in the site page:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html

Please look for `"Support Identifier"` in the page that opens, after you click on the hyperlink : `"My Oracle Support"` in that paragraph, that follows.

[EDIT (for possible answer)]: Here is some code that uses key-store and finds out the Base64 of SHA value from keyStore:

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.sample.app", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    /*Note: may be instead of converting obtained bytes into Base64, 
I should convert it into hex string.*/
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Please let me know if this suggests an answer. MD5 should be at least 32 bytes long.

Best Regards,

Your Follower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely the answer is given in the thread:

[How to read SHA and MD5 fingerprint programmatically in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45546282/787399)

Here in this answer @NateZh has used code to get "MD5" instance of Digest straight forwardly instead of "SHA", together with converting byteArray[] to HEX String, as well as providing variations:

a. Getting MD5 from signature.

b. Getting MD5 from byteArray[]

**Hints:**

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
StringBuffer md5StrBuff = new StringBuffer();
try {
messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
//... so on
```

Happy Coding and Exploring :-)

Best Regards